# Is there a way to temporarily change an int to a string in mongodb db.find?

Tags: regex, mongodb

In the collection I have there is a field that may be numbers or strings depending on what they are trying to categorize.  Each number is like a measurement plus id so the measurement would be 400 with the id .01 so it is put in as 400.01.  I do not have the ability to change this database at all but  I need to change these doubles into a string so I can perform a regex search on them.

For example I will be asked to find all ids with 400 measurements.  So I would need to collect numbers like 400.01, 400.05, etc.

So far I have

```
db.collection.find{field:{$regex:/^400/m}}
```

Which works but not for the doubles and I tried:

```
db.collection.find{{$set:{DX:DX.toString()}:{$regex:/^400/m}}
```

but it doesn't work.

example:

```
{"date":99-99-9999,"DX":400.1}
{"date":99-99-9999,"DX":"400.056"}
{"date":00-00-0000,"DX":"5n.05"}
{"date":11-11-1111,"DX":400.03}
```

Comment: If you can't modify the format, you're screwed. I don't know who came up with this compact form of storage but it's completely insane.

Comment: Wait, are they strings or numbers? Or both?

Comment: To query numbers in this manner, you'll have to fetch documents into the application. Thus eliminating all the advantages of DB query engine.

Comment: Its in both numbers and strings because there are times where gte and lte are called on it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can call $lte/$gte on strings too

Comment: Post a couple of examples of documents: one with string field, one with numeric field

Comment: Added a few examples of what I am seeing.

Comment: yeah, the only good way I see is to normalize the data (make them all strings) and fix the application so that it doesn't post new numbers. Assuming, of course, that what you say is true and these numbers are not really numbers, but tuples of info.

Comment: Better yet, convert all the strings too and store actual separate pieces of information. For example: `DX: {id: '01', measurement: 400}`